# pdb mismatched or not found - Debugging in windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-debugging

I am new to Windows programming environment. So would appreciate if you can help me with this:

I have got an application called `Controller.exe` that I am building on `TeamCity` build server. The build of the application generates `exe` file and `pdb` file.

When I run the `Controller.exe` on my deployment machine, it crashes and dump is generated.

In the application I have enabled dumping crash with the following:

```
unsigned long stackSize = 16384;
SetThreadStackGuarantee(&stackSize);
SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(WriteLargeMiniDump);
```

The function `WriteLargeMiniDump()` writes the dump successfully. I know this because when I run the `Controller.exe` on my development machine it generates dump and I can open it successfully and see the crash line in source code.

However, in the case of `exe` and `pdb` generated by TeamCity server, I can't debug the dump. When I open the dump file in `visual studio 2015` and Try to `Debug with Native Only` it says `pdb` not loaded.

I googled around to check if `pdb` file is correct. So I downloaded `Debugging Tools for windows` which as `symchk.exe`.

When I run `symchk.exe` it gives the following errors:

```
SYMCHK: Controller.exe FAILED  - Controller.pdb mismatched or not found

SYMCHK: FAILED files = 1
SYMCHK: PASSED + IGNORED files = 0
```

`Controller.pdb` is in same directory where I copied the `exe` generated from `TeamCity` server.

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: What are the file sizes of the binaries? Are we talking native C++ or .NET assemblies here? That is a strange error it almost sounds like the .pdb is getting chopped due to a copy error or a dual write error.

Comment: @justin.m.chase `exe` is around 2MB and `pdb` is around 15MB

Comment: Take a look at the time stamps as well. Maybe the build has been changed to not generate debug databases, and you are copying an outdated pdb over.

Comment: Timestamps are correct.

Comment: look which path for pdb file in exe. simply search `.pdb`  string in exe. usually in your exe - absolute path to pdb and debugger search pdn at this absolute path,but not in same folder, where exe

Comment: I figured it out. The original author of the project had checked in a copy of `Controller.pdb` in `TeamCity` server. This was wrong as `Visual Studio` expects to use `pdb` generated during the build of `exe`. Therefore, I changed the build script at TeamCity to publish the pdb that was generated duing build. Using that `pdb`, I was successfully able to debug the crash.

Comment: @Monku, Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, if possible, not add your solution as the comment, you could add it as an answer, and then mark it as the answer later. So it could help other community members who meet the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue. The problem was that the original author of the project had checked-in `pdb` into the SVN repository, which `TeamCity` was building. Therefore, the `exe` generated didn't match the `pdb`. And as per MSDN documentation, we must use the `pdb` that is generated during the build of `exe`.

Using the `pdb` generated during the build of `exe`, I was able to debug the `dump` file.

An important link that helped me understand `pdb` files is : https://www.wintellect.com/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know